# how to for loop and compare 2 csv files

Tags: python-3.x

Ok So some might have seen this code before, but I explained it very badly.

This is the cvs files im working with:

file1:

```
 Needie Seagoon 57      83  55  78      91  73  65  56          
    Eccles      98  91  80      66              77  78  48  77
    Bluebottle  61      88  80  60      45  52  91  85          
    Henry Crun  92      58  50  57      67  45  77  72          
    Minnie Bannister    51      97  52  53      68  58  70  69          
    Hercules Grytpype-Thynne        78  62  75      67              48  56  89  67
    Count Jim Moriarty  51      68  51  66      55  72  50  74          
    Major Dennis Bloodnok       54  47   59     48              66  58  53  83
```

file 2:

```
CITS1001    95
CITS1401    100
CITS1402    97
CITS2002    99
CITS2211    94
CITS2401    95
CITS3001    93
CITS3002    93
CITS3003    91
CITS3200    87
CITS3401    98
CITS3402    93
CITS3403    88
```

I am trying to normalise with scores. So I want to loop through file1 index[1] column. so

```
57
(empty)
61
92
51
(empty)
51
```

and divide each of the scores by the max score 95 in CITS1001. Also how do you loop through an empty string or value, gives me error that int() not base 10 :''

This is the best I can do so far:

```
def normalise(students_file, units_list):
    file1 = open(students_file, 'r')
    data1 = file1.readlines()

    for line in data1:
        cell = line.split(",")
        if cell == "":
            line.next()
        else:
            stu_first = int(cell[1])
            answer = stu_first / 95
            print(answer)
```

so the units_list is not added yet because I can't seem to loop thgrough students_file first. I have just added 95 to see the answer in the list.

NOTE: I am not using modules for practise atm, please don't say use csv module or panda, thanks.

advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample input is tab-delimited but your code is using `,` as a delimiter. Which delimiter is your input file actually using?

Answer (score 0):

I think python pandas are worth looking into.  This is a perfect use case for pandas.

[Compare two csv files with python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418180/compare-two-csv-files-with-python-pandas)